# What if Valgrind's detected memory loss goes from something to nothing in the course of a process?

Tags: memory-management, valgrind

If Valgrind summarizes a non-zero amount of memory as "definitely lost" and later summarizes zero memory as "definitely lost" which is it? Did it turn out to be wrong the first time or does it start counting from zero after each summary?

Comment: You need to explain what you are doing. Where are these summaries coming from? One process, or more than one process?